# Creating a list of hyperlinks in Python

Tags: python, html, hyperlink

What if I needed more than one hyperlink. Just one after another, each on a new line. I'm getting "positional argument follows keyword argument".

```
out = open("index.html", "w")
out.write(page.format(
heading = "<h1>Road Fatalities in Australia</h1>", 
contents1 = "<p>On this site you will find road fatality statistical data.</p>", 
contents2 = "<p>...</p>", 
contents3 = "<p>...</p>", 
link = '<a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a>'))
out.close()
```

I have also tried this:

```
out = open("index.html", "w")
out.write(page.format(
heading = "<h1>Road Fatalities in Australia</h1>", 
contents1 = "<p>On this site you will find road fatality statistical data.</p>", 
contents2 = "<p>...</p>", 
contents3 = "<p>...</p>", 
link = '<ul>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a></li>
</ul>'
out.close()
```

I just need the links in a list, one after another. Nothing special, like follows:

A look at Death Rates Over the Years

Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?

...etc...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error message you get in your second example?

Comment: just to clarify. You got an issue with our html formatting? Or do you want to extract the links into an python array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `positional argument follows keyword argument` that you're getting is due the way you're passing the arguments to the `page.format()` function.

In your first example `link` argument is a bunch of strings separated by the comma. But only the first line:

```
link = '<a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a>'
```

is recognized as keyword argument named `link`, rest of the lines are treated like positional arguments without keyword assigned to them. This is a violation in Python, positional (not named arguments) can only be used before keyword (named) arguments, thus an error.

In your second example you are trying to pass multiline string as `link` argument but you use single quotes to do this. In order to use multiline string in Python you must enclose it in triple quotes

```
some_string = """line 1
line 2"""
```

The easiest fix for you would be to do:

```
out = open("index.html", "w")

out.write(page.format(
heading = "<h1>Road Fatalities in Australia</h1>", 
contents1 = "<p>On this site you will find road fatality statistical data.</p>", 
contents2 = "<p>...</p>", 
contents3 = "<p>...</p>", 
link = '''<ul>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a></li>
</ul>'''))
out.close()
```

Which would create:

```
<h1>Road Fatalities in Australia</h1>
<p>On this site you will find road fatality statistical data.</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a></li>
    <li><a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a></li>
</ul>
```

given that

```
page = """{heading}
{contents1}
{contents2}
{contents3}
{link}"""
```

Answer (score 1):

use BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = '''<ul>
<li><a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a></li>
<li><a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a></li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(link,"lxml")
tags = soup.select("ul li a")
items = [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in tags]
print(items)
```

ouput

```
['fatalities_per_year.html', 'fatalities_per_state.html', 'fatalities_per_day.html', 'fatalities_per_time.html', 'fatalities_trucks.html', 'fatalities_speed_zones.html', 'fatalities_gender.html', 'fatalities_age.html', 'fatalities_user.html']
```

Comment: I didn't need to use the beautifulsoup, just needed to format the list properly like you have there.  The list comes up as a bulleted list but that's fine for this purpose.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
heading = "<h1>Road Fatalities in Australia</h1>"
contents1 = "<p>On this site you will find road fatality statistical data.</p>"
link = ['<a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a>',
'<a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a>']
with open("this.html", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(heading)
    myfile.write(contents1)
    for l in link:
        myfile.write(l)
```

OUTPUT

```
<h1>Road Fatalities in Australia</h1><p>On this site you will find road fatality statistical data.</p><a href="fatalities_per_year.html">A Look at Death Rates Over the Years</a><a href="fatalities_per_state.html">Which State has the Highest Fatality Rate?</a><a href="fatalities_per_day.html">Which Day of the Week is Deadliest?</a><a href="fatalities_per_time.html">Which Time of Day is the Deadliest?</a><a href="fatalities_trucks.html">How Many Trucks are in Fatal Crashes</a><a href="fatalities_speed_zones.html">Which Speed Zones are the Deadliest?</a><a href="fatalities_gender.html">Does Your Gender Increase the Risk of Dying?</a><a href="fatalities_age.html">Does Your Age Have Anything to do With Death-rates?</a><a href="fatalities_user.html">Fatality Data</a>
```